# Create an audio player that sits in a separate frame, trigger different audio mp3 samps from external play buttons

Tags: html, audio

Not sure know how to create this, I did test some html5  examples.

I was able to sit an audio player in a frame and add an external button that when
clicked triggered the player to start and audio sample, but I don't know how to do this with multiple audio samples and play button for each sample.

I have a joomla portal with addfullajax installed
It's loading articles with ajax,
Above the articles is a frame called drawer (im using gantry framework)

I placed the code for a html5 audio player up in the drawer position in joomla.
Then i put some code for the button into the 1st article that starts the audio player up in the drawer position.

What i'm trying to do is have several articles, each article should have an audio play button,
When you browse to a different article you click play and the player up in the drawer position will play that audio file or sample.
When you browse to a different article, it will have another play button,
When clicked it will start a different audio sample in the same player.

Can someone please show me how to create a nice player.

Thanks

Comment: In order to create a nice player use a tiny bit of css border-radius, everything looks nice with border-radius. Anything else specifically you need help with?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're talking about sorry,

Comment: Now sure what you're talking about sorry,
I need a player that is separate from the play buttons.
Each play button can sit anywhere away from the player.
Each button has a link to different audio.
Clicking any play button will load the audio into the player.
Clicking another play button will start the new audio.

I want to keep them separate from the player because I have ajax working with articles.

So I could have the player sit in the top header of my site, and control the audio with play buttons that sit in another area.

Someone please can you provide a few examples before I crack up.

Comment: sure `#playbutton{border-radius:5px;}`